# Manage hoogle index using stack tool

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hoogle

Context: Before `stack` I stopped using `hoogle` locally because my index would somehow lose sync with installed packages. If I recall correctly, I had issues with different results in `ghci`, command line and `cabal` sandboxes.

Can I leverage `stack` environment manage my local `hoogle` databases?

Comment: Keeping an eye on this [this github issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/55), might be useful. From that I'd say the answer today is probably "not yet".

Comment: `stack hoogle generate -- --local` worked for me...

Answer (score 6):

For the Hoogle part I recommend using the latest git version, which will become version 5. To install that, do:

```
git clone https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle.git
cd hoogle
stack init
stack install
```

Then generate it and use it with:

```
# generate Haddock docs for all your packages
stack haddock
# generate the Hoogle index
stack exec -- hoogle generate --local --database=.stack-work/hoogle
# perform a search for map
stack exec -- hoogle map --database=.stack-work/hoogle
# start a server at http://127.0.0.1/ to browse docs
stack exec -- hoogle server --local --database=.stack-work/hoogle
```

To make this work with Cabal instead of Stack, do `cabal install` initially, set your `haddock`/`hoogle` preference in your Cabal config file to `True`, and remove the `stack exec` bits.

Comment: This did not work for me. I get a big long list of `Packages not found: aeson ...`

Comment: ^ when trying to use `hoogle generate`

Comment: With stack 1.5.1, hoogle 5.0.13, after rather lengthy haddock phase in a project I got `Packages missing documentation: adjunctions aeson ...` and most packages are not indexed. I would prefer answer that explains what is needed, as tooling is not reliable and needs to be manually corrected.

Comment: I had to `$ find ./src/ -name '*.hs' -print0 | xargs -r0 stack exec haddock --  --hoogle --package-name MyPackage --package-version 0.1.1.1` to get hoogle docs for the library itself. Simply running `stack exec -- hoogle generate --local` just made it for the dependencies.

Comment: That is, `find ./src/ -name '*.hs' -print0 | xargs -r0 stack exec haddock -- --hoogle --package-name MyPackage --package-version 0.1.1.1 && stack exec hoogle -- generate --local && stack exec hoogle -- myQuery` instead of `stack haddock && stack exec -- hoogle generate --local && stack exec -- hoogle myQuery`